# Playing FLV/HTTP in Android application

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, flv, vlc

In my application, I need to play FLV/HTTP streams on Android (2.x+). [libvlc](http://www.videolan.org/) supports this function: I've tested my FLV streams with VLC-android player, and it seems to work.

But a year ago, one of the developers described is as follows:

> VLC on android is incomplete, unfinished, buggy, slow, it doesn't even compile.
>   Why are so much people trying to build it anyway?

So is the idea to use VLC for my project good or it's better to search some other way? Are there some other means for playing FLV on Andoid?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this library?
 http://vov.io/vitamio/ 
I am using it to play http live streams for prehoneycomb devices but it also has FLV support. When first playing a video it will prompt a user to install a plugin from the play market or from their website. After the initial install the user will should be able to play FLV.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to connect with this library's developers, but they haven't answered. 
And installing a plugin from market is not a good idea for my application. So I don't like to use it.